# Visual Studio 2010 C# Windows-Forms Editor Bug

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, custom-controls

I currently have an annoying bug with the Editor in Visual Studio 2010 Express. Whenever I add a CustomControl in the Editor, any changes I make after that to the form, isn't saved in the .cs File, which basically means that when I add f.e. a MenueStrip to the Form, the code won't be generated and will not be added to the .cs file, but it will be displayed in the Editor correctly. Any idea how I can fix this?

The Custom Control is a XNA-Control and it works properly.

EDIT: Someone suggested restarting VS. It did work but I do have another Bug now. I can now apply changes to the Form and add / delete Stuff, but when ever I run the app the CustomControl will be deleted from the .cs after I stopped debugging, which means that I need to re-add the CustomControl after every run.

**EDIT2: I found a workaround. After running the app, the Editor-Window can be bugged, so no changes you make are applied to the .cs file, a simple closing and re-oppening of the Editor of the Form will fix the Problem.**

Answer (score 0):

The one time I've come across this kind of behavior, it was related to the InitializeComponent() function signature being modified by the developer. Which is probably not the case here.

Could you post a small working example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Restarting helped to fix the problem somehow. Please see edit for the new bug!